# coding guidelines for python dictionaries

Tags: python, coding-style

I have a python dictionary, definition of which does not fit in a single line. Could anyone please tell me guidelines for python dictionaries. I currently have this which does not look good to my eyes.

```
initialstate =  {
                    'state':grid,
                    'f':find_manhattan_distance(grid,goal),
                    'g':0,
                    'h':find_manhattan_distance(grid,goal),
                    'ancestor': None
                }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`pep8.py` says:

```
mydict.py:2:28: E231 missing whitespace after ':'
mydict.py:1:15: E222 multiple spaces after operator
```

Try this:

```
initialstate = {
    'state': grid,
    'f': find_manhatten_distance(grid, goal),
    'g': 0,
    'h': find_manhatten_distance(grid, goal),
    'ancestor': None
}
```

Notice the change in spacing after commas and operators. This version passes all the `pep8.py` tests.

Comment: ugh, if pep8.py says you can't have a newline after {, then pep8.py is dead wrong.. :(

Answer (score 4):

People differ on how best to format things like this.  I prefer:

```
initialstate =  {
    'state': grid,
    'f': find_manhattan_distance(grid, goal),
    'g': 0,
    'h': find_manhattan_distance(grid, goal),
    'ancestor': None,
    }
```

Things I like about this style:

1. It allows multiple nestings easily.  Indenting under the open-brace would instead cause far too much indentation after just two levels.
2. The comma after the last item means I can add another line without changing the current last one.
3. The closing brace indented follows other Python visual style, where there is no obvious termination line, simply the undent to indicate the end of the block.

(PS: "Manhattan" has only a's in it..)

Answer (score 2):

You can choose between the following options (and some more):

```
initialstate = {
    'state': grid,
    'f': find_manhatten_distance(grid,goal),
    'g': 0,
    'h': find_manhatten_distance(grid,goal),
    'ancestor': None,
    }
```

- **Pro**: version-control friendly: lines (including the first) can be removed or inserted without affecting more than 1 line (BTW, this only applies if you add the leading `,`)
- **Pro**: Lots of horizontal space for the items
- **Con:** Maybe it's not *immediately* obvious that the dict is assigned to `initialstate`

---

```
initialstate = { 'state': grid,
                 'f': find_manhatten_distance(grid,goal),
                 'g': 0,
                 'h': find_manhatten_distance(grid,goal),
                 'ancestor': None, }
```

- **Pro**: Very compact, makes maximum use of available horizontal space
- **Pro**: Preserves the usual semantics of variable left, value right, thus making it absolutely clear what's assigned where
- **Con**: If the variable name is very long, you might run out of space
- **Con**: Not very version-control friendly: adding or removing lines or even changing the name of the variable will cause diffs

Answer (score 2):

For dictionary initializations where the keys are strings, you might try the `dict(...)` constructor with keyword arguments rather than the `{...}` dict literal syntax, because it'll remove all the extra quotes you'll otherwise find cluttering the definition.

```
initialstate = dict(state    = grid,
                    f        = find_manhattan_distance(grid, goal),
                    g        = 0,
                    h        = find_manhattan_distance(grid, goal),
                    ancestor = None)
```

As you can see, I also like to line up the equals signs so I can just scan down and easily see the assignments.

Comment: I like the `=` align too, though PEP8 says [don't do that](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#pet-peeves).  I started to convert from {} to dict() then reverted when I realized I liked the quoted strings standing out with **syntax highlighting** (e.g. green in PyCharm)

Comment: PEP8 also says: "most importantly: know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes the style guide just doesn't apply. When in doubt, use your best judgment." I do like to align things when they're on multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

PEP8 says you should avoid lining up ='s cos it's going to bite you when a longer variable name comes along and messes up your alignment.

If you're a fan of 'scanning down the list', that big gap between the identifier and the = is left-right eyeball pain. Why not align your variables so both halves are visually *next to* the assignment operator?

```
initialstate = dict(state = grid,
                        f = find_manhattan_distance(grid, goal),
                        g = 0,
                        h = find_manhattan_distance(grid, goal),
                 ancestor = None
               )
```

Bonus: new superlongvariablenames can be accommodated without having to add spacing to earlier items:

```
initialstate = dict(state = grid,
                        f = find_manhattan_distance(grid, goal),
                        g = 0,
                        h = find_manhattan_distance(grid, goal),
                 ancestor = None,
 user_selected_startpoint = 0
               )
```

Comment: what if you have `user_selected_startpoint_much_longer`? Do you shift everything right?